# JPA @ElementCollection List specify join column name

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Shirt implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max=9)
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="SHIRT_COLORS")
    @Column(name="color")
    private List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
```

The collections table created when I set hibernate to autocreate is

```
SHIRT_COLORS
 shirt_id
 color
```

How do I annotate my Entity so that the join column isn't a concatenation of the entity and pk so that the the table created is:

```
SHIRT_COLORS
 id
 color
```

I've tried @JoinColumn but that didn't work.  In actuality, the SHIRT_COLORS table in production is managed outside of the app and the column names are already defined.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this:

```java
@Entity
public class Shirt implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max=9)
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "SHIRT_COLORS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @Column(name="color")
    private List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
```

Comment: that works but with a slight edit as follows: referencedColumnName = "id").

Comment: @jeff: Right. When `referencedColumnName` is used in a `CollectionTable` mapping, the referenced column (`id`) is in the table of the entity containing the collection. I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks for the remark, Jeff.